# Facebook Multi language Application

Tags: php, facebook

how can i develop  multi language app in Facebook

Comment: please ask specific questions. This is one is too broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the user's setting for language from the GraphAPI with [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) by looking at the "locale" entry in the "user" table.

Then simply have a switch in your application that takes notice of this (would suggest you retrieve it from Facebook only once at the start of the session).

If you are using the REST API, which is deprecated, then the information is avaiable from the [users.getInfo](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getInfo/) method, again as "locale".

Comment: but i already done in Old Rest API so is it possible in Old api

Comment: @HeartDisk - have updated my answer with information for the rest api.